# How to pass a value from template to ts function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

Hi I have a list which dynamically fetches list of barcodes from localstorage.

**COMPONENT FILE**

```
<div class="scan-list">
    <table *ngFor="let item of fsubList">
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Reel No: {{item.barcodeno}}</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Date: {{item.datetime}}</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Vendor: {{item.vendor}}</h3></td>
            <td class="red"><a (click)="viewdet()">View Details</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So what i want to do is to fetch the particular row value `{{item.barcodeno}}` after clicking on `viewdet()` and then pass it on to the ts file in the function `viewdet()` so that i can perform further operations with that fetched value.

Comment: You can pass it like (click)="viewdet(item.barcodeno)"

Comment: ok Paresh but then how will i get it in my typescript code here 

```
 viewdet() : void {
 //I WANT THAT VALUE HERE
  }
```

Comment: in ts file you have to declare function with one argument man like viewdet(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

Template:

```
<td class="red"><a (click)="viewdet(item.barcodeno)">View Details</a></td>
```

TS:

```
viewdet(barcodeNo) {
}
```

Comment: and i how will i get the value in the function viewdet(barcodeNo)

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <td class="red"><a (click)="viewdet(item.barcodeno)">View Details</a>
```